# How can I access hardware time from browser

Tags: javascript, web-applications, offline, offlineapps

I'm developping an offline web application and I'm trying to find any datetime available, on the device running the app, that is not editable by the user. I have to be able to access it through javascript. The reason is that I want my application to be insensitive to time change hack on mobiles. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't throught javascript, maybe you can limit the hack by launching a javascript timer at the launch of the webapps and use it to check the time instead of the time of the device ? It depends on the accuracy you want but something like that will be updated every second :

```
var time = new Date();

function loop(){
     setInterval(function(){ time=new Date(time.getTime() + 1000);loop(); }, 1000);
}
loop();
```

So the time variable is the real time elapsed since the launch of your apps.
Downside of this, it will use ressources...

Comment: Indeed, this is a partially good idea. Probably the best I can find so far. The thing is that the user can change his setting before openning his browser and I can't do nothing do detect that.

Comment: Then you have to synchronize the app with your server whenever the user is online. Since I don't know the goal of your app, It's difficult to find a proper solution. Maybe you can provide more informations ?

Comment: I'm doing a punch card application. Some user are working in bad reception zones where the internet connection can be lost for several days. I thought about the sync with server idea but then if the user close his browser or web page my time variable get cleared. If the user reopen the app while ofline, I have no more synced reference.

Comment: You can use localstorage or a cookie to store it, but if the user changes his device's time between two uses it will be tricky, because you won't know if your stored value is still relevant...